# Advice for optimising Mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

Hi I have this mysql query from a php application. According to Cpanel -> metrics -> resource usage, is hogging a lot of resources. Please can anyone suggest any ways to optimise it. I have included the schema too.

```
$q = "SELECT businesses.id 
    FROM businesses 
        JOIN businesses_business_types ON businesses_business_types.business_id = businesses.id 
        JOIN business_counties ON business_counties.business_id = businesses.id 
        JOIN business_details ON business_details.business_id = businesses.id 
    WHERE (
            businesses_business_types.business_type_id = $cat 
            OR businesses.primary_business_type_id = $cat
        ) 
    AND 
        (
            business_counties.county_id = $county 
            OR businesses.primary_city = $county
        ) 
    AND business_details.status = 2 
    AND businesses.status = 13 
    LIMIT 1";
```

**business_counties**
Field   Type    Allow Null  Default Value P
id  int(11) No
business_id int(11) No
county_id   int(11) No

**business_details**
Field   Type    Allow Null  Default Value P
id  int(11) No
business_id int(11) No
image   varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
logo    varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
image_draft varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
logo_draft  varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
description text    Yes NULL
description_draft   text    No
status  int(11) No  0
modified    datetime    No
created datetime    No
uk_description  text    Yes NULL
uk_description_draft    text    Yes NULL

**business_types**
Field   Type    Allow Null  Default Value P
id  int(11) No
name    varchar(255)    No
parent_id   int(11) No  0
description text    Yes NULL
display_order   int(11) Yes 0
level   int(2)  No  1
display_in_nav  int(2)  Yes 0

**businesses**
Field   Type    Allow Null  Default Value P
id  int(11) No
name    varchar(255)    No
postcode    varchar(50) No
primary_city    int(11) No
actual_location int(11) Yes NULL
primary_business_type_id    int(11) Yes NULL
notes   text    Yes NULL
status  int(2)  Yes 0
created datetime    Yes 'NULL'
updated datetime    Yes 'NULL'
business_address_1  varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
business_address_2  varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
business_address_3  varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
business_city   varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
business_county varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
business_postcode   varchar(50) Yes 'NULL'
billing_address_1   varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
billing_address_2   varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
billing_address_3   varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
billing_city    varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
billing_county  varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
billing_postcode    varchar(50) Yes 'NULL'
salesman_id int(11) No  0
next_callback   datetime    Yes 'NULL'
business_function   varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
bunsiness_type  varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'
rating  int(11) Yes 0
business_type_tags  text    Yes NULL
show_on date    Yes 'NULL'
trial_start date    Yes 'NULL'
trial_end   date    Yes 'NULL'
added_by    int(11) Yes 0
latitude    double  Yes NULL
longitude   double  Yes NULL
multiple_email  tinyint(1)  No  0
website varchar(255)    Yes 'NULL'

**businesses_business_types**
Field   Type    Allow Null  Default Value P
id  int(11) No
business_id int(11) No
business_type_id    int(11) No
level   int(2)  No  2

Comment: First run an explain on your query

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: If you are going to show us the relevant parts of your schema, and thats a good idea,  please Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` in phpMyAdmin or similiar or the mysql command line and copy/paste the output to your question and format it. That makes it much more readable

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: @ RiggsFolly - thanks I will try 'explain'. I don't think it's open to injection though as the 2 $variables are not provided by the user. Noted about 'SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName', thanks.

Comment: @Impaler - this query is testing whether a category is empty, and thus whether to display it in a menu listing, hence t is searching for a truth condition more or less. I assumed 'LIMIT 1 ' would cut it short if it's true (avoiding further unnecessary searching) and that ORDER would induce another overhead so left it out. If the query would be quicker with ORDER I will include it?

Answer (score 2):

It's tricky to optimize queries with `OR` expressions. See my answer to [Optimizing for an OR in a Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1677805/20860) for an explanation.

The common solution is to separate the terms of the `OR` expression into separate queries, and combine the queries with `UNION`. Unfortunately, in your case you have two different `OR` expressions, each with two terms. So you end up with 4 queries to union together to cover all the combinations.

```
SELECT businesses.id
FROM businesses
    JOIN businesses_business_types ON businesses_business_types.business_id = businesses.id
    JOIN business_counties ON business_counties.business_id = businesses.id
    JOIN business_details ON business_details.business_id = businesses.id
WHERE business_details.status = 2 AND businesses.status = 13
AND businesses_business_types.business_type_id = 1234
AND business_counties.county_id = 5678
UNION
SELECT businesses.id
FROM businesses 
    JOIN businesses_business_types ON businesses_business_types.business_id = businesses.id
    JOIN business_counties ON business_counties.business_id = businesses.id
    JOIN business_details ON business_details.business_id = businesses.id
WHERE business_details.status = 2 AND businesses.status = 13
AND businesses.primary_business_type_id = 1234
AND business_counties.county_id = 5678
UNION
SELECT businesses.id
FROM businesses
    JOIN businesses_business_types ON businesses_business_types.business_id = businesses.id
    JOIN business_counties ON business_counties.business_id = businesses.id
    JOIN business_details ON business_details.business_id = businesses.id
WHERE business_details.status = 2 AND businesses.status = 13
AND businesses_business_types.business_type_id = 1234
AND businesses.primary_city = 5678
UNION
SELECT businesses.id
FROM businesses
    JOIN businesses_business_types ON businesses_business_types.business_id = businesses.id
    JOIN business_counties ON business_counties.business_id = businesses.id
    JOIN business_details ON business_details.business_id = businesses.id
WHERE business_details.status = 2 AND businesses.status = 13
AND businesses.primary_business_type_id = 1234
AND businesses.primary_city = 5678
LIMIT 1;
```

To support the conditions for both WHERE and JOIN, add these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE businesses ADD KEY status_primarycity (status, primary_city);
ALTER TABLE businesses ADD KEY status_primarybusinesstypeid (status, primary_business_type_id);
ALTER TABLE businesses_business_types ADD KEY businessid_businesstypeid (business_id, business_type_id);
ALTER TABLE business_counties ADD KEY businessid_countyid (business_id, county_id);
ALTER TABLE business_details ADD KEY status_businessid (status, business_id);
```

When I test the query, the indexes are used, and all the table references are optimized. I think they will all get the covering index optimization too (but in my test I have no data, so I think I'm seeing some weird choices from the optimizer).

Here's the EXPLAIN:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | businesses |  | ref | PRIMARY,status_primarycity,status_primarybusinesstypeid | status_primarycity | 5 | const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | businesses_business_types |  | ref | businessid_businesstypeid | businessid_businesstypeid | 8 | test.businesses.id,const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | business_counties |  | ref | businessid_countyid | businessid_countyid | 8 | test.businesses.id,const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | business_details |  | ref | status_businessid | status_businessid | 8 | const,test.businesses.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 2 | UNION | businesses |  | ref | PRIMARY,status_primarycity,status_primarybusinesstypeid | status_primarycity | 5 | const | 1 | 100 | Using where |
| 2 | UNION | businesses_business_types |  | ref | businessid_businesstypeid | businessid_businesstypeid | 4 | test.businesses.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 2 | UNION | business_counties |  | ref | businessid_countyid | businessid_countyid | 8 | test.businesses.id,const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 2 | UNION | business_details |  | ref | status_businessid | status_businessid | 8 | const,test.businesses.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 3 | UNION | businesses |  | ref | PRIMARY,status_primarycity,status_primarybusinesstypeid | status_primarycity | 9 | const,const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 3 | UNION | businesses_business_types |  | ref | businessid_businesstypeid | businessid_businesstypeid | 8 | test.businesses.id,const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 3 | UNION | business_counties |  | ref | businessid_countyid | businessid_countyid | 4 | test.businesses.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 3 | UNION | business_details |  | ref | status_businessid | status_businessid | 8 | const,test.businesses.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 4 | UNION | businesses |  | ref | PRIMARY,status_primarycity,status_primarybusinesstypeid | status_primarycity | 9 | const,const | 1 | 100 | Using where |
| 4 | UNION | businesses_business_types |  | ref | businessid_businesstypeid | businessid_businesstypeid | 4 | test.businesses.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 4 | UNION | business_counties |  | ref | businessid_countyid | businessid_countyid | 4 | test.businesses.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 4 | UNION | business_details |  | ref | status_businessid | status_businessid | 8 | const,test.businesses.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
|  | UNION RESULT | <union1,2,3,4> |  | ALL |  |  |  |  |  |  | Using temporary |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pJJcUq1T1MFjhCeKfiEKVV/0)

Comment: Wonderful response, thanks Bill. I will add the Indexes you suggest. I definitely need to know if there's a business in a particular category and county but I might be able to remove the ORs in the WHERE and AND clauses. Would that enable a better optimisation or is simply removing them enough? thanks, John