# Postgresql Sorting a Joined Table with an index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm currently working on a complex sorting problem in Postgres 9.2
You can find the Source Code used in this Question(simplified) here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9857e/11

I have a Huge (>>20Mio rows) table containing various columns of different types.

```
CREATE TABLE data_table
(
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  column_a character(1),
  column_b integer
  -- ~100 more columns
);
```

Lets say i want to **sort** this table **over 2 Columns** (**ASC**).
But i don't want to do that with a simply Order By, because later I might need to **insert rows** in the sorted output and the user probably only wants to see **100 Rows at once** (of the sorted output).

To achieve these goals i do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE meta_table
(
 id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
 id_data bigint NOT NULL -- refers to the data_table
);

--Function to get the Column A of the current row
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_column_a(bigint)
 RETURNS character AS
 'SELECT column_a FROM data_table WHERE id=$1'
 LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

--Function to get the Column B of the current row
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_column_b(bigint)
 RETURNS integer AS
 'SELECT column_b FROM data_table WHERE id=$1'
 LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

--Creating a index on expression:
CREATE INDEX meta_sort_index
 ON meta_table
 USING btree
 (get_column_a(id_data), get_column_b(id_data), id_data);
```

And then I copy the Id's of the data_table to the meta_table:

```
INSERT INTO meta_table(id_data) (SELECT id FROM data_table);
```

Later I can add additional rows to the table with a similar simple insert.
To get the Rows 900000 - 900099 (**100 Rows**) i can now use:

```
SELECT get_column_a(id_data), get_column_b(id_data), id_data 
FROM meta_table 
ORDER BY 1,2,3 OFFSET 900000 LIMIT 100;
```

(With an additional INNER JOIN on data_table if I want all the data.)
The Resulting Plan is:

```
Limit (cost=498956.59..499012.03 rows=100 width=8)
-> Index Only Scan using meta_sort_index on meta_table (cost=0.00..554396.21 rows=1000000 width=8)
```

This is a pretty efficient plan (Index Only Scans are new in Postgres 9.2).
But what is if I want to get Rows 20'000'000 - 20'000'099 (**100 Rows**)? Same Plan, much longer execution time. Well, to improve the Offset Performance ([Improving OFFSET performance in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618366/improving-offset-performance-in-postgresql)) I can do the following (Let's assume I saved every 100'000th Row away into another table).

```
SELECT get_column_a(id_data), get_column_b(id_data), id_data 
FROM meta_table 
WHERE (get_column_a(id_data), get_column_b(id_data), id_data ) >= (get_column_a(587857), get_column_b(587857), 587857 )
ORDER BY 1,2,3 LIMIT 100;
```

This runs much faster. The Resulting Plan is:

```
Limit (cost=0.51..61.13 rows=100 width=8)
-> Index Only Scan using meta_sort_index on meta_table (cost=0.51..193379.65 rows=318954 width=8)
Index Cond: (ROW((get_column_a(id_data)), (get_column_b(id_data)), id_data) >= ROW('Z'::bpchar, 27857, 587857))
```

So far everything works perfect and postgres does a great job!

Let's assume I want to change the Order of the 2nd Column to **DESC**.
But then I would have to change my WHERE Clause, because the > Operator compares both Columns ASC. The same query as above (ASC Ordering) could also be written as:

```
SELECT get_column_a(id_data), get_column_b(id_data), id_data 
FROM meta_table 
WHERE 
   (get_column_a(id_data) > get_column_a(587857)) 
OR (get_column_a(id_data) = get_column_a(587857) AND ((get_column_b(id_data) > get_column_b(587857)) 
OR (                                                  (get_column_b(id_data) = get_column_b(587857)) AND (id_data >= 587857)))) 
ORDER BY 1,2,3 LIMIT 100;
```

Now the Plan Changes and the Query becomes slow:

```
Limit (cost=0.00..1095.94 rows=100 width=8)
-> Index Only Scan using meta_sort_index on meta_table (cost=0.00..1117877.41 rows=102002 width=8)
Filter: (((get_column_a(id_data)) > 'Z'::bpchar) OR (((get_column_a(id_data)) = 'Z'::bpchar) AND (((get_column_b(id_data)) > 27857) OR (((get_column_b(id_data)) = 27857) AND (id_data >= 587857)))))
```

How can I use the efficient older plan with DESC-Ordering?
Do you have any better ideas how to solve the Problem?

(I already tried to declare a own Type with own Operator Classes, but that's too slow)

Comment: Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677538/advanced-indexing-involving-or-ed-conditions-pgsql I tried UNIONS. It's a little bit better than the last Plan, but it's still not enough.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9857e/28/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rethink your approach.  Where to begin?  This is a clear example, basically of the limits, performance-wise, of the sort of functional approach you are taking to SQL.  Functions are largely planner opaque, and you are forcing two different lookups on `data_table` for every row retrieved because the stored procedure's plans cannot be folded together.

Now, far worse, you are indexing one table based on data in another.  This *might* work for append-only workloads (inserts allowed but no updates) but it will *not* work if data_table can ever have updates applied.  If the data in data_table ever changes, you will have the index return *wrong* results.

In these cases, you are *almost* always better off writing in the join as explicit, and letting the planner figure out the best way to retrieve the data.

Now your problem is that your index becomes a lot less useful (and a lot more intensive disk I/O-wise) when you change the order of your second column.  On the other hand, if you had two different indexes on the data_table and had an explicit join, PostgreSQL could more easily handle this.